# How does: $\sin^3(x) = (\cos^2(x)-1 )(-\sin(x))$

Tags: trigonometry

So I'm trying to integrate: $\sin^3(x)$ My book says:

$$G(x)=\int \sin^2(x) \times \sin(x) \,\, dx$$ 
I do not understand the following step:
$$\int -(1-\cos^2(x)) \times -\sin(x) \,\, dx$$

---

$$\int (\cos^2(x) -1)\,\, d\cos(x)$$
$$\int (u^2 -1) du$$
$$\frac{1}{3}u^3-u+c = \frac{1}{3}\cos^3(x)-\cos(x)+c$$

In other words how do you go from: $$\sin^3(x) = (\cos^2(x)-1) \times -\sin(x)$$

I appreciate it,

Cro-Magnon.

Comment: $sin^3(x)=sin^2(x)sin(x)=(1-cos^2(x))sin(x)$

Comment: @lulu I thought the same thing but my books says what I've written in my answer..

Comment: They used exactly what lulu said but also introduced 2 negative signs (since the product of $-1$ with itself is $1$), and distributed one of the negative signs into the $cos^2(x)$ term

Comment: Your identity is hard to parse, because the parentheses don't line up.  I took it to read $sin^3(x)=(cos^2(x)-1)\times (-sin(x))$ which is the same thing I wrote (once you note that $ab=(-a)\times (-b)$).

Comment: @Brenten Ah I see! These negative signs always trip me up -.- Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin(x)^3=\sin(x)^2 * \sin(x)$$
$$\sin(x)^2=1-\cos(x)^2=-(\cos(x)^2-1)$$
$$\sin(x)^3=(1-\cos(x)^2)\sin(x)=-(\cos(x)^2-1)\sin(x)=-\sin(x)*(\cos(x)^2-1)$$

That's how they break $\sin(x)^3$ apart. This is generally the method used to integrate anything involving odd powers of the sine and cosine functions. Things get more interesting for the even powers, when you have to use the power reduction formulas.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\cos^2(x) - 1\right)\cdot\left(-\sin(x)\right) = 
\left(-\sin^2(x)\right)\left(-\sin(x)\right) = \sin^3(x)$$

Comment: Thanks! These negative signs always trip me up